# Scapy Sniff Segmentation Fault on OSX

Tags: python, macos, scapy

I am trying to use scapy to sniff out wireless access points, but whenever I run the script nothing is printed and I get a Segmentation Fault: 11

I am using Python 3.4 and am running OSX

Here is my code(Its fairly common - used from tutorials on other sites):

```
import sys
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *

ap_list = []
d = {'counter' : 0}
def PacketHandler(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 8:
            d['counter'] += 1
            if d['counter']>500:
                sys.exit()
            if pkt.addr2 not in ap_list:
                ap_list.append(pkt.addr2)
                print("AP MAC: %s with SSID: %s" %(pkt.addr2, pkt.info))

sniff(iface = "en0", prn = PacketHandler)
```

Comment: What happen when you run your code with python 2 instead of python 3?

Answer (score 3):

To sniff scapy requires to run as sudo.